# Two Temporary Table with same name in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, foxpro

We are rewriting a foxpro database to SQL. I encountered the following scenario. Foxpro can create two cursors with the same name under two different `if` statements.

I tried to do the same in SQL. Created two temporary tables. Something like below:

```
IF @id = 1
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO #abc from table1
END

IF @id = 2
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO #abc frm table2
END
```

NEXT here I write a code to update the values of a temporary table column with another column. But sql throws me an error saying 'there is already an object named #abc in the database'.

Can I please have a solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: Do `table1` and `table2` both have the same structure? Also what RDBMS are you using now? SQL Server?

Comment: Don't do a direct conversion from foxpro. If you know what you want at the output to be work to that and ignore the FoxPro way of doing things (obviously don't ignore the logic0. Your code should be about 1/20th of the size and a lot easier to handle.

Comment: Martin, I am using SQL Server and yes, both tables have the same structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your specific use case given that both have the same structure you could use.

```
IF @id IN ( 1, 2 )
  BEGIN
      SELECT *
      INTO   #abc
      FROM   table1
      WHERE  @id = 1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT *
      FROM   table2
      WHERE  @id = 2
  END
```

to avoid the parser issue you are encountering. I agree with Ben's comment though that a literal translation of the FoxPro code is likely going to lead you with an inefficient and unmaintainable mess.

Comment: this works if my table structure is same. I have a similar requirement, except that I have different table structures now.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of creating the table with `SELECT INTO`, why not define the table first and then `INSERT` (assuming that the temp table structure is the same for both)?

```
CREATE TABLE #abc (Col1 Int, Col2 varchar(50))

IF @id = 1
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #abc SELECT * from table1
END

IF @id = 2
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO #abc SELECT * from table2
END
```